# Reasons for random switch to "limited connectivity" under Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, networking, connection

What are the various reasons for a single laptop computer to repeatedly randomly switch to "limited connectivity" on a previously working wireless network - sometimes after a couple of minutes, sometimes after an hour or longer? Here are various other facts of interest:

- Computer is running Vista Home
- Other (laptop and desktop) computers work fine in the wireless network without losing their connections.
- The network adapter is Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection
- After losing the connection, the only way to reconnect is to either reboot the computer or deactivate and reactivate the network adapter.
- The connection is lost when the computer hits a high CPU load, for example when running Flight Simulator X.
- Signal quality is great, even with limited connectivity (5 out of 5 bars)
- Power Saving Mode is on "Loud Environment" mode, i.e. the highest power setting.

Let me know if I'm missing any important information.

**Edit 1** - see this thread for some ideas. None of them work for me however. :-/ http://www.vistaforums.com/forum/Topic4198-45-14.aspx

**Edit 2** - for anyone else visiting this, you could try the latest Intel driver (June '09): http://is.gd/3o0wh This seems to have worked for me! (*fingers crossed*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the new (June '09!) [Intel 3945ABG driver](http://is.gd/3o0wh). That seems to have worked for me - at least, the steps I used to reliably reproduce the problem (start up Flight Simulator X, fly around a minute) now no longer reproduce the problem, I haven't had the connection drop off since.

Answer (score 2):

Change the Power Saving Mode of your WLAN adapter to 'Disabled' or CAM (Constantly Awake Mode).

[image]

Comment: Great idea, unfortunately it hasn't helped. Any other ideas?

Comment: use some up-to-date Linux Live CD (e.g. Ubuntu 9.04) and see if the wireless connection works flawless there (to rule out faulty hardware)